# How add opencv to Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I added the opencv library and include file to visual studio 2019. (Property pages / VC++ directories / include directories & library directories. also, linker / input / and add the name of the library to this part).Also, I added the bin file to the environment variables. It's working well but every time that I want to work with OpenCV I must do all these things again. This is really boring
Is there another solution to add these files? (I mean no need to add files again)

Comment: you can inherit project settings. But typically, for toy projects, I just copy a "basic project" that I created once. Dor serious projects I adjust the project setting once according to the project's needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really looking for the fastest option I would recommend using [vcpkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019).
Once you set it up and install your needed library, using it in your project is as simple as using the standard library, you just have to include the library headers.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @sinaghadirialamdari please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

CMake can generate project files for several prominent IDEs, such as Microsoft Visual Studio, Xcode, and Eclipse CDT. It can also produce build scripts for MSBuild or NMake on Windows; Unix Make on Unix-like platforms such as Linux, macOS, and Cygwin; and Ninja on both Windows and Unix-like platforms.